# First element indented

Tags: html, css

Why is the first element in my div indented and the following ones aren't?
It won't even move up and down. It's driving me crazy...

It doesn't react to margins top and bottom. Only to left and right but by default it is kinda centered even do I didn't set it to be there.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>PrevodEngleskog</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>

    </head> 

    <body>

        <div id="strana">

            <header>

                <img id="logo" src="C:/users/Aca/Desktop/sajt/slike/eng.png">

                <nav>

                    <ul id="navbar">

                        <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">About me</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">Prices</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">Gallery</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>

            </header>

            <div id="main">

                <div><a class="button" href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">Hello</a></div>
                <div><a href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">Hello</a></div>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <div><a href="file:///C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/prvisajt.html">Hello</a></div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

css

```
body {
background-image: url("C:/Users/Aca/Desktop/Sajt/Slike/pattern.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
}
#strana {
margin: auto;
background-color: white;
width: 800px;
height: 2000px;
}

header {
background-color: white;
border: solid red 2px;
height: 100px;
}

#logo {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
width: 143px;
height: 120px;
margin-top: -17px;
padding-right: 47px;
}

nav {
background-color: white;
/*border: solid red 2px;*/
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 100px;
height: 70px;
width: 400px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: left;
}

#navbar {
position: absolute;
width: 350px;
display: inline-block;
/*border: solid red 2px;*/
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
margin: 12px 22px 0px 22px;
text-align: center;
}

li {
margin-left: 0px;
display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
text-decoration: none;
color: red;
font-family: cursive;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
border: solid red 2px;
padding-left: 3px;
padding-right: 3px;
}

.nav:hover {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

#main {
height:400px;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
}

.button{
}
```

[And on the site it looks like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX6CB.png)

Thanks!

Comment: It works fine with the code you provided.  See this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/9kaq1Lur/  I'm guessing it's another element in your page causing this.  Can you post the entire html?

Comment: Still working even with that. Only other thing I'm not seeing is your external stylesheet. What's in stylesheet.css?

Comment: Maybe there is a :first-child element somewhere in your stylesheet.css which causes it or :nth-child(1).

Comment: I'm guessing, you haven't cleared a float somewhere or your button class is causing it.  Please post relevant styles

Comment: I'll post the whole css now.

Comment: Also please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Pete Oh, thanks! I'll have that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float: left` on your #logo is causing the issue.  Remove it and you should be good to go.

```
#logo {
display: inline-block;
width: 143px;
height: 120px;
margin-top: -17px;
padding-right: 47px;
}
```

See this fiddle for an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/9kaq1Lur/2/

Also, here is a great read on floats.  They are very confusing until you've worked with them for a while:  https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Oh, btw.. Do you maybe know why it won't react to top and bottom margin settings? :)

Comment: It is for me.  I added margin-left: 40px; to the button class and it put a 40 pixels margin before the first div.

Comment: Yeah.. Side margins work. xD But bottom and top one not. :D But thanks! Helped a lot man!

Comment: Oh.. Found out! :D